# How to define a function that calculate reciprocal rank and mean reciprocal rank in a list? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and I still not know so much about coding.
This is what I got for Wikipedia :

[image]

Comment: What's the query, what's the response?

Comment: What does mean reciprocal rank? What did you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c1 = Counter(list1)
>>> c2 = Counter(list2)
>>> def rec_rank(key,dic):
...     return dic[key]/float(sum(dic.values()))
... 
>>> rec_rank('apple',c1)
0.3333333333333333
>>> rec_rank('apple',c2)
0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
count = 0
for i in list:
    if i == string:
       count += 1.0
return count / len(list)
```

This is wrong.

Comment: no I mean a function that can calculate the reciprocal rank such as for the first link if I type the function -> fruit('apple'), the result will be 1/3 for list1  as it has only appear once in a list. But for the second list the result will be 1/2 as it occurs two time in a list

Comment: @Erika I looked it up in wikipedia. It does not depend on the number of correct items in the sequence. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank

Comment: ah yeah! My bad :( it depends on the rank as well..

Answer (score 1):

```
len(filter(lambda x: x == 'apple', list1)) / float(len(list1))

sum(map(lambda x: x == 'apple', list1)) / float(len(list1))

reduce(lambda x, y: x + (y == 'apple'), list1, 0.0) / len(list1)
```